# How to code this in SQLite?

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Hi I am teaching myself SQL using an app for Android that uses SQLite. This particular app does not show correct coding, only error statements, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is the question (and the answer should use the ***NOT*** operator):

***List the first name, city, and invoiced amount of the customers whose invoices are not $37 and who do not live in Paris. Do not use the inequality operator (<>).***

The table name  is *Customer*. 
Variables are *FirstName*, *City*,  and *InvoiceTotal*

Comment: Looks like pretty straightforward SQL: "select FirstName, City, InvoiceTotal from Customer where not(InvoiceTotal = 37) and not(City = "Paris")

Comment: Thanks; I was putting the "not" in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

Use the code something like i have provided.You can also use != which is the same as <>;

```
SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE not(InvoiceTotal = 37) and not(City = "Paris");
```